# What is the correct usage of the comma in the phrase "that combined have"?

Tags: commas

I have the following sentence:

> The forecast entails logic and confidence that combined have proven to be profitable.

I have seen uses of "*that combined have*" without any commas as above, and some cases where they insert two commas as follows:

> The forecast entails logic and confidence that **, combined,** have proven to be profitable.

Which is the correct, or more appropriate way?

Comment: IMHO, both"...that combined have..." and "...that, combined, have..." are correct and acceptable; but "...that, combined, have..." is a bit clearer and probably a better choice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general reference question.

Comment: Use _together_. Then you don't have to worry about a comma.

Comment: _The forecast entails logic and confidence which together have proven profitable._

Answer (score 1):

Generally, *that* is used in defining/restrictive relative clauses only. Such clauses define the antecedent (the noun they refer back to): if a defining relative clause is left out, our understanding of what the antecedent refers to changes substantially. Example:

> I like Frenchmen who smell of garlic. (I like only those Frenchmen that smell of garlic.) (Defining.)
>
> I like Frenchmen, who smell of garlic. (I like (all) Frenchmen; they smell of garlic.) (Non-defining.)

Defining clauses generally have no comma, whereas non-defining ones do. *That* is normally only used with defining clauses. The following would be the meaning of the sentence if the relative clause were non-defining:

> The forecast entails logic and confidence; combined, those have proven to be profitable. (This is probably what you mean; then it must be *which* with a comma after *confidence*, as follows:)
>
> The forecast entails logic and confidence, which combined have proven to be profitable. (The commas around *combined* I would consider possible, but only optional.)

The defining interpretation would be thus:

> The forecast entails only such logic and confidence as combined have proven to be profitable (and no other kinds of logic and confidence). (This is probably not what you meant, but it's possible in theory. Then it would be *that* and no comma.)